# HTML Helper Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using this code and is working fine.

```
@Html.TextBox("myname", "somevalue", new { @class = "css-class", @onclick = "alert('demo');" id="mynewID"})
```

But there is another overload for this:

```
HTMLHelper.Textbox(string name, object value, IDictionary<string,object> htmlattribute)
```

I am using like:

```
@Html.TextBox("myname", "", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "f","class","ds" } })
```

but getting compilation error...please help

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is due to the incorrect syntax used in the dictionary initializer. You can see that easily if you add this code to a class and try to compile:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "f", "class", "ds" } };
```

You will see that you get the error:

> No overload for method 'Add' takes 4 arguments

You need to pass each object to the dictionary as a key value pair, as in this code (notice each key-value pair surrounded by curly brackets):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "f" }, { "class", "ds" } };
```

So you can use that overload of the HtmlHelper as in the following example:

```
@Html.TextBox("myname", "", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "f"}, {"class", "ds" } })
```